# jQuery function history.replaceState() removes additional parameters from the URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following jQuery code which closes bootstrap modal on click of back button. It's working fine. However, when it closes the modal it should remove the the `#my-modal-id` from the URL bar, which it does. But, while doing that it also removes the additional "required" parameters from the URL. For example:

It works fine when the URL is: `http://localhost/gamearena/index.php#my-modal-id`. Here it removes `#my-modal-id` from the URL bar as per the script. So far so good.

However, it messes up when the URL has additional parameters like 
`http://localhost/gamearena/index.php?ref=shreyansh#sidebar-left`. Here, it even removes `?ref=shreyansh` along with it. How do I control it so that it only removes the modal id set by itself earlier.

Here is the code:

```
// Close model on clicking back button / swiping back
  $('div.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    var modal = this;
    var hash = modal.id;
    window.location.hash = hash;
    window.onhashchange = function() {
      if (!location.hash){
        $(modal).modal('hide');
      }
    }
  });
  $('div.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    var hash = this.id;
    history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
  });
  // when close button clicked simulate back
  $('div.modal button.close').on('click', function(){
    window.history.back();
  })
  // when esc pressed when modal open simulate back
  $('div.modal').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
      window.history.back();
    }
  });
```

**EDIT**

After diagnosing a little I found out that the line `history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);` is responsible for changing the content of the URL here, i.e., removing the hash and other parameters. Further, I noticed that `window.location.pathname` grabs the URL only upto the `index.php` and not the parameters beyond it. Hence, in my opinion the function reverts back the URL to the state `index.php` instead of `index.php?ref=shreyansh` as it cannot recognize it. Therefore, I come to a conclusion that if `window.location.pathname` is replaced by a function which has the ability to fetch the URL up to `index.php?ref=shreyansh` (the location before adding the hash part), the problem will be solved. Hence, experts are requested to throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

instead of using

```
window.history.back();
```

if you want to remove hash from the URL. It will also trigger `window.onhashchange`

Comment: I will try.. Give me a minute. However, in the meantime I want to mention that when I tried commenting block of codes from bottom I found out that it's `history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.pathname)` which is removing the hash along with the parameters. Hence, in my opinion changes are required on this line. Please consider having a look.

Comment: Tried, not working. As I said it's the above line causing the issue. `window.history.back();` should not be an issue as it should go from `http://localhost/gamearena/index.php?ref=shreyansh#sidebar-left` to `http://localhost/gamearena/index.php?ref=shreyansh` (in my opinion).

Comment: I have edited the question above, please watch out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't updating the history when it sets the hash, so `history.back()` reverts to the earlier URL state.

This will update the hash and the history:

```js
function addHash (hashString) {
  let myHash = '#' + hashString;
  location.hash = myHash;
  history.replaceState(null, null, myHash);
}
```